# Checking if the Checkbox is checked or not dynamically in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a Checkbox dynamically by this button code

```
private void btn_add_record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)q2
{
CheckBox DeleteCheckBox = new CheckBox();
Point P_request = new Point(nXCheckBox, nYCheckBox);
DeleteCheckBox.Location = P_request;
DeleteCheckBox.Name = "CH"+Record_ID+"";
}
```

Then i Checked it manually
Then i need to check a specific checkbox its name is "CH"+Record_ID+" to be checked or not dynamically using this code

```
string ChechBoxName = "CH1";
CheckBox DeleteChechBox = new CheckBox();
DeleteChechBox.Name = ChechBoxName;
if (DeleteChechBox.Checked)
{
 // To Do Code
}
```

When i debug this code, it doesn't enter the if statement .. WHY ?

Comment: What about checking the checkbox first? ;)

Comment: Are you sure `.Checked` property is `true`?

Comment: Yes i am sure because i checked the Checkbox manually

Comment: @user3634515 You checked **a** `CheckBox`, but you didn't then test the same one in your condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking if the box is checked before it gets checked.  Add

```
DeleteChechBox.CheckedChanged += DeleteChechBoxCheckedChanged;
```

and add the method DeleteChechBoxCheckedChanged where you can test whether or not it's been checked.  You can also use

```
DeleteChechBox.Checked = true;
```

to check the box through code.

**Edit:**
To get a certain checkbox by it's name you have to either store it as a global variable or look through the controls array in the form.

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.Name == "CH1")
    {
         CheckBox DeleteChechBox = (CheckBox)control;
         if (DeleteChechBox.Check)
         {
             //To Do Code
         }        
     }
}
```

Comment: I need to check the checkbox manually not dynamically and i need to return either it checked or not dynamically

Comment: because the context where the checkbox was created is different from where you are reading the checked value, this is how you have to find which checkbox you are talking about

Comment: like Xylorast describes, by looping through the controls in the form until you find one with a name or other attribute matching the one you want to get a value from

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new CheckBox, the default `Checked` value is `false`. Therefore `if (DeleteChechBox.Checked)`
returns false which is why you don't enter the block. You're not checking any existing Checkboxes, you're checking the new one you created.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant. Maybe you already checked it..?

```
string ChechBoxName = "CH1";
CheckBox DeleteChechBox = new CheckBox();
DeleteChechBox.Name = ChechBoxName;
DeleteChechBox.Checked = true;
if (DeleteChechBox.Checked)
{
 // To Do Code
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is another way of accessing the control instead of enumerating over all the controls on the form for each control you would like to access:

```
Dictionary<string, CheckBox> checkBoxCollection = new Dictionary<string, CheckBox>();
```

And in your method where you create the checkbox add it to the dictionary:

```
checkBoxCollection.Add("CH1",DeleteCheckBox);
```

Access the checkbox from wherever you want like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox;
bool success = controls.TryGetValue("CH1"), out checkBox);
if (success)
{
    // To Do Code
}
```

Or in your CheckedEvent you can get the CheckBox being checked like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you can accomplish it like shown in the following code snippet (pertinent to your example):

```
string _strCheckBoxName = "CH1";
CheckBox DeleteCheckBox= new CheckBox();
DeleteCheckBox.Name = _strCheckBoxName ;
DeleteCheckBox.Checked+=(s,e)=>CheckBox_Change(s,e);
DeleteCheckBox.Unchecked+=(s,e)=>CheckBox_Change(s,e);
DeleteCheckBox.IsChecked = true;

private void CheckBox_Change(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if ((sender as CheckBox).Name=_strCheckBoxName && (bool)(sender as CheckBox).IsChecked)
  {
    // To Do Code
  }
}
```

In suggested solution, you essentially subscribe the newly created `CheckBox` control to a single event handler proc, which looks at the control name and if checked runs some code. If more `CheckBox` added, then use the same event-subscription technique pointed to the same handler, and extend it with another if statement (or `if-else if`, or `switch` statement).

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating one `CheckBox` in your `btn_add_record_Click` handler and then creating a new one in your second code fragment, which just happens to have the same `Name` as the first. That notwithstanding, it is not the same check box, so will not have the same value for its `Checked` property.

The way to fix that is to create the checkbox in the form's constructor as a class member, and then discover it when you need it by searching the `components`, using the code which [Xylorast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3763597/xylorast) showed:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.Name == "CH1")
    {
         CheckBox DeleteChechBox = (CheckBox)control;
         if (DeleteChechBox.Check)
         {
             //To Do Code
         }        
     }
}
```